# How to debug process' inability to print to console

Tags: c++, debugging, embedded-linux, gpio, beagleboneblack

I am using a Beaglebone black to generate a square wave on one of its GPIO. This is done to trigger an ultrasonic sensor which in reply, send the ECHO pin high (when it has results to share). I modified Derek Molloy's [example on GPIO](https://github.com/derekmolloy/exploringBB/blob/version2/chp06/GPIO/simple.cpp) and it now looks like this

```cpp
/* 
Run: 
∼/exploringbb/chp06/GPIO$ g++ simple.cpp GPIO.cpp ‐o simple ‐pthread
∼/exploringbb/chp06/GPIO$ sudo ./simple
*/

#include<iostream>
#include<unistd.h> //for usleep
#include<chrono>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include"GPIO.h"
using namespace exploringBB;
using namespace std;

int main(){
   GPIO outGPIO(44), inGPIO(45);
   struct timeval tv;
   outGPIO.setDirection(OUTPUT);


   int delay_us = 50;//50us
   // Basic Input example
   inGPIO.setDirection(INPUT);
   while(1)
   {
        //double start, end;
        std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point start,end;
        long long delay_count=0.0;

        // Trigger
        outGPIO.setValue(HIGH);
        usleep(10);
        outGPIO.setValue(LOW);

        // Poll for Echo pin to go HIGH
        while(inGPIO.getValue() == 0)
        {
                usleep(1000);
                start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        }
        while(inGPIO.getValue() == 1)
        {
                end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
                usleep(delay_us);
                delay_count +=delay_us;
                //printf("\n!!getvalue==1");
        }
        // calculate distance
        long long microseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(end-start).count();
        printf("\nDuration: %lld, delay: %lld dist:%f",microseconds,delay_count,(microseconds+delay_count)*0.034*0.5);
        usleep(1000*100);
   }


   /*outGPIO.streamClose();*/

   return 0;
}
```

I noticed that the program prints the resutls for a while and then hangs there with no CPU overloading (observed via `htop`) and no kernel error (observed via `dmesg -Hw`).

I am failing to debug this issue as I can't corner it yet.

Comment: "*to generate a square wave*" -- No, you're only sending one pulse. A wave would have a frequency and duty cycle. And you need to explicitly initialize that output pin to a known (low) level. Your simple code to detect pin level changes is not robust; it's prone to hanging if it ever misses a fast response. "Fast" is relative to your (slow) sampling rate. Use a logic analyzer on both pins to capture the actual timing when your code hangs. "*I noticed that the program prints the resutls for a while*" -- Are those results even reasonable/correct measurements?

Comment: Drop that C code, install `libgpiod` and its Python bindings. With a few line in Python you will get better results independently on the board.